# Does the number of rows after outer merge depend on the intersection of the keys?

Tags: pandas, merge

The shape of df is (315360, 4) and fd2's shape is (214704, 4).

df:

| Country | Partner Country | Year | Variable1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Turkey | Spain | 1993 | 183188 |
| Spain | Turkey | 1993 | 3918281 |
| US | UK | 1993 | 495949282 |
| US | UK | 1994 | 495949282 |
| UK | US | 1994 | 495949282 |

df2:

| Country | Partner Country | Year | Variable2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Syria | Spain | 1993 | 183188 |
| Turkey | Spain | 1993 | 3918281 |
| US | UK | 1993 | 495949282 |
| Germany | UK | 1994 | 495949282 |
| UK | US | 1994 | 495949282 |

```
df.merge(df2, how="outer", on=["Country", "Partner Country", "Year"])
```

data shape I get after the merge is (351351, 5). is the following statement correct? The reason I get less than 530064 rows is that there are rows which are contained in both datasets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `concat` with `drop_duplicates`:

```py
df = pd.concat([df, df2]).drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: Could you explain what the duplicates mean in this case? Does it imply the duplicates in each data set separately or after merging them there are some duplicates and this function drops them?

Comment: It means that there are duplicates in the merged dataframe. After the merge, any duplicated (all values in the row are the exact same with another row, if the variables are different, they aren’t duplicates) will be removed

Comment: But why would we have duplcıates after the merge?

Comment: It’s just a habit. If you would like, you can remove that part from the code.

Comment: Indeed there were some duplicates but I do not know why merge function creates duplicates.